# Using root to modify the size() method of a linkedStack class java

Tags: java, stack

I have been given a `LinkedStack.java` class with properties `Node root` and `int size`.

I am to modify the methods to remove the size property altogether and have every method do exactly as instructed. I've figured out how to modify all methods to remove the size property and still work properly except for the `size()` method. Could someone maybe point me in the right direction of how to go about solving this?

```java
public class LinkedStack implements Stack
{
    private Node root;
    private int size;

    public LinkedStack()
    {
        root = null;
    }

    public void push(Object o)
    {
        Node n = new Node(o, root);
        root = n;
    }

    public Object pop()
    {
        if(root==null)
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't pop from empty stack");

        Object result = root.getValue();
        root = root.getNext();
        return result;
    }

    public Object peek()
    {
        if(root==null)
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't peek at empty stack");

        return root.getValue();
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return size;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return root==null;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String str = "(top) [ ";
        Node n = root;
        while(n!=null)
        {
            str += n.getValue() + " ";
            n = n.getNext();
        }
        return str + "]";
    }
```

Also here is the `Node` class if needed.

```java
public class Node
{
    private Object element;
    private Node next;

    public Node(Object o)
    {
        element = o;
    }

    public Node(Object o, Node n)
    {
        element = o;
        next = n;
    }

    public Object getValue()
    {
        return element;
    }

    public Node getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node n)
    {
        next = n;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a `size` method using recursion.
If `root` is `null` (stack is empty) return `0`.

Else call recursive `private` `size` method. If your current `Node` has next `Node` call `size` method on next `Node` and increment `size` variable by one. If there is no next `Node` just return the counted `size`.

```java
    public int size() {
        return root != null
                ? size(root, 1)
                : 0;
    }

    private int size(Node node, int size) {
        Node next = node.getNext();
        return next != null
                ? size(next, size + 1)
                : size;
    }
```